# django: serve static assets *without* copying them (collect static)

Tags: python, django

I'm hosting a django project on heroku, which limits the total app size to 300MB, and I have a lot of static assets to be served. because of django "collectstatic" which copies all the static assets to another directory, I exceed that limit.

now I know the right way to do it is to serve the static assets from an external file storage service (like amazon S3 bucket), but I have my reasons why I don't want to use an external storage service and that's out of the question.

so I'm asking this: how can I use django to serve static assets directly from their original folders WITHOUT copying them to another destination?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
python manage.py collectstatic --link
```

From
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---link:

> -l
>
> --link Create a symbolic link to each file instead of copying.

This way they won't use up extra space, if the Heroku systems allow symbolic links.

Comment: done, but looks like Heroku calculate the size of links for their full size so I'm still blocked. your solution is correct, but I need to talk with Heroku team about this. thanks :)